# HTML5 Input Validation with Custom Message

Tags: html, validation

I'm trying to validate two input boxes and display a custom error message using HTML5 browser validation.

- First input should be at least 3 characters, no custom error.
- Second input should be at least 4 characters, with custom error.

The validation doesn't seem to work with my second input, I'm always prompted with my custom error message. When I remove the `oninvalid` it works.

Where am I going wrong?

My HTML is below;

```
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="min 3" pattern=".{3,}">
  <input type="text" placeholder="min 4" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Must be 4 Characters')" pattern=".{4,}">
  <input type="submit" value="Check"></input>
</form>
```

I'm sure it's something obvious.. any help is appreciated.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2va0r6jm/10/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the [`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) attribute to restore the validity of the form like this: `oninput="setCustomValidity('')"`.

This has a side effect and it is that if you type an invalid input and submit the form and type again another invalid value immediately the default message is shown instead of the custom one until you click again the submit option.

(See this forked [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lealceldeiro/fre1dcqz/), or below working snippet)

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern=".{3,}" placeholder="min 3">
  <input type="text" placeholder="min 4" pattern=".{4,}" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Must be 4 Characters')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
  <input type="submit" value="Check" />
</form>
```

Another option would be adding an inline text with `title` attribute. The text will be appended after the default error message (See below snippet)

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern=".{3,}" placeholder="min 3">
  <input type="text" placeholder="min 4" pattern=".{4,}" title="Must be 4 Characters">
  <input type="submit" value="Check" />
</form>
```

Comment: The inputs need the attribute `required` to be considered for validation on submit. As was, all the inputs were css input:valid, and the forms could be submitted with two empty string values, regardless of any pattern specified.